# UWP Community Toolkit with source code

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

"UWP Community Toolkit" is good tool.
https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master

but If we installed it with NuGet, 
We can not access source code ( I thought ).
Now, I only want to use "RadialGauge" only in this toolkit.
and I want to modify "RadialGauge" a bit.. 
then, I started to use RadialGauge with source code without NuGet install.

**here is my step.**

1. I open New UWP project with C# VS 2017.
2. I installed this code to my "Controls" folder.   [UWP RadialGauge Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/RadialGauge)
3. and I make this project.

but No display, Just white UWP windows is opened... Why ?
I need help... with my poor UWP knowledge, to resolve is not possible...

[image]

Here is project file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/alvw6wcbiv5itsp/RadialGaugeTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: According to your steps you aren't trying to display it (but since you don't show the actual code that is supposed to display it, that's just an assumption). But why do you need to access the source code? Do you want to modify the toolkit itself?

Comment: yes.. I want to modify Toolkit itself.   I want to separate color with angle. First is green, Next is yellow, 90-100% is Red.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a *custom control*, most of the time you want to give it a default style. This style needs to be placed inside a `ResourceDictionary` called `Generic.xaml` which then needs to be inside a *folder* called **Themes**.

In your case, you have only copied the *code* part over. To make the control show up on your page, all you need to do is go grab its default style from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/1a583e41ea69f4709f5a823c451a2c96337f6223/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/RadialGauge/RadialGauge.xaml), put it in a `Generic.xaml` resource dictionary, and then put the dictionary into a folder called **Themes**.

Comment: Thank you , Justin !  I success to display it : )   It is good starting point that I will learn "Custom Control" , I did not know it yet hehe.

Comment: as Another way, after Install Nuget ,     To make Colored RadialGauge, Is it possible to "Overwide" RadialGauge Class into Colored type ?

Comment: I haven't really looked into its code but as long as it's not `sealed`, you should be able to *extend* it. :)